# React Native - Select multiple styles

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native, styles

With React.js we could select among multiple styles using classes as follows:

```
           <div
              className={
                `r-n-cal-day 
                ${i % 7 == 6 ? classes.weekend : ''}
                ${classes.day} ${bsMonth !== this.props.viewBsMonth ? classes.dayMuted : ''} 
                ${this.isSameDate(adDate) ? classes.today : ''} 
                ${this.isSameDate(adDate, this.state.selectedDate) ? classes.selectedDay : ''} 
                `
              }
              key={`${bsDate} ${bsMonth}`}
              onClick={() => this.onDaySelect(adDate)}>
              {calFns.toDevanagariDigits(bsDate)}
            </div>
```

I was trying to achieve this way of choosing the style in React-Native.

I could choose among two styles using ternary operator as follows:

```
        <Text style = { 
          index % 7 == 6 ? styles.weekend : styles.day_text
          }>
            {day.bsDate}
        </Text>
```

But to select like the one among several styles , what should we do?

if statements inside doesnot work with JSX. Can somebody suggest something ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass Array into you style like:

```
  <View style={[styles.powerblue,{marginLeft:10}]} />
```

variable styles:

```
const styles  = StyleSheet.create({
  powerblue:{width: 50, height: 50, backgroundColor: 'powderblue'},
  rightStyled:{marginRight:10},
});
```

Here it will apply style from both styles and inline stye, you can pass other stylesheet object like:

```
 <View style={[styles.powerblue,{marginLeft:10},styles.rightStyled]} />
```

But it right most properties will override left one.

e.g. if `styles.powerblue` have property marginRight as 0, and 
`styles.rightStyled` has have property marginRight as 10. Then marginRight 10 will gets applied as it is on right most side

Answer (score 0):

Do the if statement in javascript, store the result in a local variable, and use the variable in your JSX.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this way

```
 <View style={this.some(1)}></View>
```

And for the style(You can customize it as you want)

```
 some(s) {
        if(s===1)
        return {
            flex:1,
          borderRadius: 12,
         backgroundColor:'red',
        }
        else
        return {
            flex:1,
          borderRadius: 12,
         backgroundColor:'white',
        }
      }
```